# ExoMedia can't play m3u8 url

Tags: android, exoplayer, m3u8

I'm using Android 5.1+ with this library https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/, I know that this library provide VideoView can play m3u8 url. But when i try it doesn't work. Here is the [link](https://vtv.vn/du-bao-thoi-tiet/ban-tin-thoi-tiet-12h30-07-11-2018-333503.htm) of website i get m3u8 url from it 's Rss. I 've try some other sample m3u8 url and it works fine. So maybe the problem is the link of this website but i don't know why, any helps ?

```
private void setupVideoView() {
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://hls.mediacdn.vn/vtv/2018/11/7/0711thoi-tiet-12h30-1541575206215339010832-8cab6.mp4/master.m3u8"));
}

@Override
public void onPrepared() {
    videoView.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HlsMediaSource

```
    HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(hlsVideoUri), dataSourceFactory, mainHandler, new AdaptiveMediaSourceEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadStarted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCompleted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCanceled(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadError(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded, IOException error, boolean wasCanceled) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpstreamDiscarded(int trackType, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDownstreamFormatChanged(int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaTimeMs) {

        }
    });
    player.prepare(hlsMediaSource);
```